# How to left and right align text in multiple select option in Bootswatch

Tags: forms, text, bootstrap-4, alignment, bootswatch

I'm using Bootswatch Sandstone https://bootswatch.com/sandstone/

And I have a form with source code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
  <select multiple="" class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
    <option><p class="text-left">Subject 1<p><p class="text-right">500 views</p></option>
    <option><p class="text-left">Subject 2<p><p class="text-right">400 views</p></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How to left and right align text values within the options?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to have different formatting within an option tag. One option you could use is have information appear as a tooltip using the title attribute like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
  <select multiple="" class ="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
    <option title="500 views">Subject 1</option>
    <option title="400 views">Subject 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```